# Editing Meta Data in PDF using Lotus Notes

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, lotus-notes, lotus

I have an application, which has pdf attachment inside documents. Need to edit the pdf meta data and append or add document information(some field values from document) into that pdf.

I want to add the values into meta data so that when pdf is printed these values should not be seen. If we go to File Properties of any pdf we can find Author and other information, it should similarly show field values which I want to insert.

All above functionality has to be done using Lotus Notes, might be any tool can help.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail on which language you are using, how do you intend to call it (agent, button)?

Answer (score 1):

I am using CutePDF SDK in one of my recent project to manipulate PDF files. You install a COM object on the system (cclient or server) where the code is executing, then you can update meta data like author, etc. Even password protect the file if you like.
You can download a demo version here: http://www.cutepdf.com/solutions/formsdk.asp

In your case, you must detatch the PDF file first, the perform the changes and then reattach it to the Notes document.

Comment: I used CutePDf a ton from LotusScript applications. For XPages and Java I have used PD4ML which is morre robust that iText in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

If Java is an option you can try iText. http://itextpdf.com/

We use that to generate PDF's from Lotus.